# Flask jinja2 update div content without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

Need achieve some features like [http://webonise.co.uk/][1] when click on  contact,resume,resources link will update (location URL&div content) but  without refresh the page.

### Flask view function

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('Welcome')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

---

Under **index.html** is extends **base.html**

```
{% block content %}
    {{super()}}
    <section class="content">
        <a href="#"><i class="mdi-event"></i>Event</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="mdi-contact"></i>Contact</a>
        <div class="board">
            {# dynamic template #}
            {# without using {{% include 'event.html' %}} #}
        </div>
    </section>
{%- endblock %}
```

---

How can i dynamic rendar **event.html** / **contact.html** content when different link is click and rendar under **{# dynamic template #}** without refresh the page ?

```
<!--event.html-->
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <h3>123</h3>
        <p>abc</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### What I try

import jinja2 Environment but still no idea how to achieve this

```
env = Environment(autoescape=True,
loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))
@app.route('/')
def index():
    board = env.get_template('event.html')
    flash('Welcome Home Tyler')
    return render_template('index.html', board=board)
```

Is there really need ajax technique get/post method to achieve all this?

Comment: You need JavaScript for this.

Comment: @ArunGhosh can you show me some example or technique? and suggest some js.library to handle this , thanks

Comment: You can jQuery library for this purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Flask-Sijax](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Sijax/) which helps you add Sijax support to your Flask app. [Sijax](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sijax) is a python/jquery library that makes AJAX easy to use on your web applications. Alternatively you could do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#next').click(function() {
           $.ajax("{{ url_for('yourroute') }}").done(function (reply) {
              $('#container').html(reply);
           });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" id="next" value="Next" />
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Is there some rule of tumb when to use Flask-Sijax and when to use the jquery snippet?

Comment: jquery is easier, compared to adding an extension.

Comment: this example does not work?